# Github actions decline action if fails

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to use the github actions for first time, I've created and followed the tutorial from github and my `.github/workflows/push_main.yml` is :

```
name: Android CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11

      # Runs ktlint
      - name: Lint
        run: ./gradlew ktlintCheck

      # Execute unit tests
      - name: Unit Test
        run: ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

Also what I'd like to have is when trying to do a rebase or merge to `main` have this check and if it works then keep the action of `rebase` or `merge` I thought to do something like, create a temporal branch do the check there and if it works do the `rebase` or `merge` into main and then delete the temporal branch but I don't know if there's any other efficient way to do so. Also I've seen that I can run the jobs in parallel will it make it faster?

Comment: Hi StuartDTO. What problem are you facing at the moment? What is the error on your workflow run and how can we reproduce it? _(Note: It's probably not related, but I observed you're currently using the `actions/checkout@v1` at the beginning how your workflow, but this version is outdated, you should use `actions/checkout@v2`)._

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd, thanks for replying what I'd like to have is a pipeline that when I create a PR checks all of this efficiently I don't know if doing in parallel will work, but then when merging before it, trying if it breaks something with this checks and then if it fails then don't merge, is that possible? Or it is done automatically? Like, merge develop to main check first if fails don't merge

Comment: Did you check the [protected branches and required status check documentation](https://github.blog/2015-09-03-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks/)? That way, you can prevent PR to be merged if a github action workflow fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a super convenient way to build, test and aggregate the outcome of changes of some branch before merging using pull requests.

Its common to create a pull request and trigger a workflow doing the checks. Just add "pull_request:" to reuse your existing workflow, to build and test your changes.

```
name: Android CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11

      # Runs ktlint
      - name: Lint
        run: ./gradlew ktlintCheck

      # Execute unit tests
      - name: Unit Test
        run: ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

Jobs are executed in parallel. Of course that is faster. Common use case is a matrix that defines required test targets, e.g. os versions, [node](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-multiple-versions-of-nodejs) or Java versions.